# Replace a portion of url in python

Tags: python, selenium

I need to replace a portion of following url in selenium webdriver+python:

https://ve-215:8443/cloudweb/dropbox_authorized?oauth_token=l8eYuFG8nux3TUHm&uid=69768040

I need to replace `ve-215` to a ip address say `192.168.24.53`

I tried using `replace` but it doesnt work.

Following is code I am using:

```
current_url=driver.current_url
print(current_url) #prints the url of the current window.

current_url.replace("ve-215", "192.168.53.116")
print(current_url)  #print url with replaced string
driver.get(current_url) #open window with replaced url
```

Can anyone help me with what is wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 3):

`replace` method does not modify the string itself (strings are immutable in Python) but returns a new string. Try

```
current_url = current_url.replace("ve-215", "192.168.53.116")
```

That being said, it is advised to use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) module ([`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html) in Python 3) for parsing and reconstructing URLs.

Answer (score 2):

The `replace` method returns a string with the modifications applied but does not modify the current string.

You should use it that way :

```
current_url = driver.current_url
print(current_url) #prints the url of the current window.

current_url = current_url.replace("ve-215", "192.168.53.116")
print(current_url)  #print url with replaced string
driver.get(current_url) #open window with replaced url
```